# POI JAVA appending cell without affecting cell format

Tags: java, apache-poi

Im trying to append a cell in a sheet, for example the cell 1A has a border and filled with color grey and I want to insert a string "hello", but using

```
cell.setCellValue("hello");
```

destroy the cell format or rather make the cell format in default mode. I know how to use the

```
CellStyle cs = workbook.createCellStyle();
```

method but in my project I'm inserting many different data with different cell format. I googled it and no luck finding an answer.
Is there another way to solve my problem?

To elaborate my problem.
In my sheet in 1A I have a cell format
[Cell format (fill with color grey and have thin border)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hEf2.png)

but when I use

```
 cell.setCellValue("hello");
```

it makes the cell's format become default but I want my cell to become like this without using `CellStyle cs = workbook.createCellStyle();`
[cell I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoyob.png)

Is there a way to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POI - How do I set cell value to Date and apply default Excel date format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794659/poi-how-do-i-set-cell-value-to-date-and-apply-default-excel-date-format)

Comment: It's not about formating the data before inserting

Comment: tl;dr: set value first, then set style.

Comment: the thing is I have many data to be inserted with different cell format, I just want to know if there is an easy way to do this

Comment: Again: Create your styles first, then populate, then set styles [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529542/changing-cell-color-using-apache-poi/11530150#11530150)

Answer (score 5):

I believe you have an excel workbook and you wanna append data to it. If you wanna keep the existing format and insert data to it you can do that using below code

```
cell = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("Hellooooo");
```

but if you are create a new cell by using

```
cell = sh.createRow(0).createCell(0);
```

then you're destroying the current format, in that case you have to create all required `cellStyle` all over again.

Comment: wooh I thought that my problem have no solution, I manage to do the cellstyle method and finish my project using that but thanks for the info :D

Comment: I want to vote up your answer but don't have enough rep to do that, many thanks anyway :D